# How to use self signed certificate with a web socket

Tags: ssl, https, websocket, tls1.2

I am running a dev server locally to test. The page is served via HTTPS on port 8000 and uses self signed certs. I have to manually accept the self signed certs when I connect with my browser. The web page that is served also connects to another locally running process through web sockets (on port 4433 instead), and that process uses the same certificate that the web server uses. The problem is that I have to also connect to the wss server through https in my browser, just to accept the same certificate again. Why is that the case? Is it because different ports are used? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Are you saying you get prompted twice, once for the initially connection and once for the wss connection?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk well yes the wss only prompts when u connect to it via HTTPS, otherwise the web socket just errors